# How to Get Open File Path

Tags: c++, filepath

Hi  please can anybody help me to get a Open File Path . For Ex: If I open a File Saved in   the location  C:\NewFolder\Hello.txt , i need to get a same file path from C++ code . help me plz ..

Comment: What do you mean, with "get a Open File Path"? - "i need to get a same file path from C++ " In what language do you get the file path now"? Please explain your question more precisely.

Comment: Hello Mr Manuel Amstutz, it means if there is a file on desktop if i opened that i have get what is path of that file thats waht i needed , my question is very clear u did'n get that ...that's it ..

Comment: i think he wants this: "C:\NewFolder\" ?

Comment: ``const char* OpenFilePath = "C:\\NewFolder\\Hello.txt"`` ?

Comment: Your question is *not* clear; saying it's clear doesn't make it so. Maybe it would be better if you showed the code you would like to write, and why it's not working. I think we're going to communicate better in C++ than English.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171573/how-to-get-filepath-from-file-handle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open files on your drive using fstream's open() function, then read the file with, for example, getline().

On Windows, you need to make sure to escape the backslashes in the filepath, e.g. C:\newFolder will be interpreted by the compiler as "C:" + newline + "ewFolder", so you need to write C:\\newFolder instead.

Example:

```
#include <fstream>
// [...]
ifstream in_file;
in_file.open("C:\\NewFolder\\Hello.txt");
if (in_file.good()) { // check to make sure the file was opened correctly
    char outbuf[1024];
    while (in_file.getline(outbuf,1024)) {
        // do something with outbuf
    }
}
```

If you are trying to do lots of file I/O, you might also want to take a look at [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which has a certain initial learning curve but makes dealing with files/directories very easy once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

First declare fstream library in your header this way.

```
#include <fstream>
```

Then create an object for input stream.

```
ifstream read ;
```

Open the file this way.

```
read.open ("C:\NewFolder\Hello.txt") ;
```

I think thats what you want to say by Open File Path.
Thought it is better if you keep the text file in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking.

If you want to know where you saved a file, well, you saved it and there is nothing more needed to know the path. The answer in this case is just "remember where you saved it". The same applies if you want to know the path of a file you opened. You opened it, how can you *not* know the path?

If you want to allow users to select a file visually on Windows, look up [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).